# DynamoDbException: Conditions can be of length 1 or 2 only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am from SQL background and very new to Dynamodb. I have a single table like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
 | dbId | genId | colData | deviceId | updateOn | params |
-----------------------------------------------------------
 |      |       |         |          |          |        |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
```

Here `dbId` is primary key and `genId` is sort key. I have created two local secondary indexs in `deviceId` and `updateOn`. In SQL I can query from the table:

```
String dbId  = "151/2020-21";
int deviceId = 1001;
long updOn   = 1608456211308;
String query = "select * from tableName where dbId = '"+dbId+"' and deviceId != "+deviceId+" and updateOn > " + updOn;
```

In DynamoDb my keyConditionExpression is : `dbId = :dbId and updateOn > :updateOn and deviceId != :deviceId`. It gives me error :

```
DynamoDbException: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: "!", near: "deviceId !="
```

I removed the `'!'` to this : `dbId = :dbId and updateOn > :updateOn and deviceId = :deviceId`. It gives me error:

```
DynamoDbException: Conditions can be of length 1 or 2 only
```

How can I perform my desired query in Dynamodb? How should I design my Dynamodb table (I mean, primary key, indexes etc) so that I get the same sql like result?

Answer (score 16):

When it comes to `query()` in dynamoDb, it is recommended to specify only the partition key and sort key in `KeyConditionExpression`.

So if you want to perform the `query()` with more conditions, you should consider `FilterExpression`. E.g:

```js
const params = {
    TableName: 'table-name',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'pk = :pk AND sk = :sk',
    FilterExpression: 'dbId = :dbId and updateOn > :updateOn and deviceId != :deviceId',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':pk': '12345',
      ':sk': 'lorem-ipsum',
      ':dbId': '0987654321',
      ':updateOn': '2022-06-25',
      ':deviceId': '123',
    },
  }

  const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  const result = await docClient.query(params).promise();
```

Comment: In DynamoDB, you cannot use a FilterExpression along with a KeyConditionExpression in a Query operation.
You will get `ValidationException: Query key condition not supported` error

Answer (score 10):

Now, reason you are facing error 'Conditions can be of length 1 or 2 only' is because you are specifying 3 conditions within KeyConditionExpression. Please specify only partition key and sort key.

Lastly, you don't need to create a LSI for this purpose. You can perform same operation on original table or need to add Global Secondary Index, **Which can help you to achieve the query on two conditions only.**

As mentioned, the attribute included in "KeyConditionExpression" should be your hash key only, matching your base table schema. If you want to query on all Then this not possible because there will be no sort key in any case as recommended by AWS Doc's.

Comment: I've switched back to RDBMS and solved the problem. Thank you @Abdul Moeez

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara That's great but If my answer is helpful to you somehow then vote up for the community. Thanks!

Comment: It's weird that even when it's not possible, I can actually perform a query based on 3 conditions on the AWS Dynamodb console

Comment: @RicardoCamacho I think you're doing a DynamoDB Scan. That's different from a DynamoDB Query.

Comment: This answer doesn't provide any code sample and doesn't help much!
An explanation is always welcome, but we should always post a code example to help the community understand what you are alluding to.